# json decoded array in foreach loop

Tags: php, json

im having trouble printing values from a json_decoded array.

```
<?php

class calculate {

    public function random_stuff()
    {
        $users_array = array(
            'attributes'  => array(
                'age'       => '25', 
                'height'    => '1.75cm', 
                'weight'    => '70kg'
            ),
            'savings'     => array(
                'cash'      => 3000,
                'bank'      => rand(1, 222)
            )
        );

        $users_array = json_encode($users_array);
        $value       = json_decode($users_array, true);
        return $value;
    }

}

$calculate = new calculate;
$arr = $calculate->random_stuff();
foreach($arr['attributes'] as $row)
{
    echo '<br />' . $row['height'];
}

?>
```

All I get is:
Warning: Illegal string offset 'height' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php on line 30

2
Warning: Illegal string offset 'height' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php on line 30

1
Warning: Illegal string offset 'height' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php on line 30

7

What am I doing wrong? I've checked some similar stack topics and it seems like I'm doing it the right way?

Comment: Why are you json encoding just to then immediately json decode?

Answer (score 0):

The message says you are trying to access a key of the array that is not defined.

This is because if you loop $arr['attributes'] you will have in return all the key pair defined inside attributes.
To understand it better, try to print_r($arr['attributes'] or even better try to echo $row without ['height'].

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over this array with `foreach($arr['attributes'] as $row)`

```
        array(
            'age'       => '25', 
            'height'    => '1.75cm', 
            'weight'    => '70kg'
        ),
```

So on the first iteration, $row is the string '25'

Square brackets applied to a string indicate you want to extract a character from a numeric offset, but `$row['height']` obviously isn't a valid offset, and you get the error.

If you just want the height, it would be something like this

```
$arr = $calculate->random_stuff();
echo '<br />' . $arr['attributes']['height'];
```

Finally, when you have problems like this, a simple approach is just to `var_dump()` variables at various points to check your assumptions are valid.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over an object, not an array. When you do:

```
foreach($arr['attributes'] as $row)
{
    echo '<br />' . $row['height'];
}
```

`$row` is '25' then '1.75cm' and finally '70kg'. If you want to access "height" do this

```
print($arr["attributes"]["height"]);
```

If you want to iterate over all your attributes

```
foreach($arr['attributes'] as $name => $value)
{
    print("attribute $name = $value <br>");
}
```

Comment: In his example, $arr['attributes'] is an array, not an object. Your answer is still correct though

Comment: Yes, that's true. PHP is not clear to define arrays and objects but as long as I'm concerned arrays are numbered lists of values (each value has a number pointing to it) and objects are named lists of values (each value has a name pointing to it). Of course this definitions may change depending of the language but I always try to categorize those in my mind :)